# Host a file on Windows server 2008

Tags: android, hosting, windows-server-2008

easy question probably:

I have a server running windows server 2008 r2. I have an android application .apk file, that I want to be available to download onto android devices locally (both on same network). How do I go about doing this? Where do I put the .apk file, and how do I navigate to it on android?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a website on your server and place your apk file under it. From the client (Android device), you can navigate to it using the browser.